# Problems with defbibentryset sorting

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have been using biber/biblatex for a while now and I was used to define multiple citations with defbibentryset and the subentry option for biblatex. This worked nice but since the last update I have a problem with how references are ordered. For example if I define 3 `\defbibenetryset` they are numbered from 1 to 3 in the bibliography no matter if there are other single citations between them. In order to check this problem I compiled again an old file that worked, but it is not working any more:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} %environnement du document
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %prise en charge des caractères spéciaux
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} %langue
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{csquotes} %pour la biblio
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,subentry,maxnames=20]{biblatex} %style acs
\bibliography{library}  
\uchyph=0


%pour réussir à faire des notes de bas de page
    \makeatletter

    \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker,sorting=none}

    \DeclareCiteCommand{\notefullcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
    {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
     \usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
     \usebibmacro{notefullcite}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
     {}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
      \usebibmacro{postnote}}

    \newbibmacro*{notefullcite}{%
     \ifciteseen
      {}
       {\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
          \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}.}}}
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\superfullcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
     {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
     \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
     \iffieldundef{prenote}
         {}
         {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
      \iffieldundef{postnote}
      {}
      {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
      {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
     \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
     {}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

    \newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
     \ifciteseen
     {}
     {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
          \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
             \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}

    \newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
    \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
    \cbx@citehook
    \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
    \let\cbx@citehook=\empty

    \makeatother




\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamelast}




\begin{document}

\defbibentryset{metarev}{Furstner2000,Roy2000} 
a\superfullcite{metarev}\\
a\superfullcite{Schwab1995}\\
a\superfullcite{Scholl1999}\\
\defbibentryset{hov}{Kingsbury1999,Garber2000} 
a\superfullcite{hov} \\
a\superfullcite{Grela2002} \\

\end{document}
```

the output should be ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4, ref5 in the bibliography, but it gives ref1, ref3, ref4, ref2, ref5. The set=hov is numbered 2!!!

cheers

Comment: This could be a bug, I'm looking into it

Comment: It was a bug. Please update to the biber 1.1 development beta on SourceForge and try it again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose this should be an answer ... this was a bug in biber 1.0 which should be fixed in 1.1 which is in beta on SourceForge.

Comment: Is this possibly an issue with biber 2.2?  I had to add an explicit `\nocite{}` in addition to the `\defbibentryset{}` recently to get the sorting working again.